# Got NaN when converting from timedelta64 to float

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

so I have a data frame that looks like this:
[image]

I calculated the duration by using the following code:

```
df['dropoff_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['tpep_dropoff_datetime'])
df['pickup_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['tpep_pickup_datetime'])
df['duration'] = df['dropoff_time'] - df['pickup_time']
```

and I am trying to convert the duration of a taxi ride from timedelta64 to float by using the following code:

```
df['duration'] = df[:5]['duration'] / np.timedelta64(1, 's')
```

However,it seems like the second time I run the code above to convert from timedelta64 to float, I keep getting this message:
[image]

Below is a picture showing the datatypes of each column:

[image]

So I am getting the float type for the duration column which is what I want, however, some of them are returning a NaN value as shown in the picture, I don't really understand why I am getting this and how to solve this... Can someone please help?

Comment: Image are very poor media to exchange textual data. Would you mind copy paste data instead of loading screenshot. It will reduce your footprint, increase the quality of your post and meet the stack standard.

Comment: Why do you need this?  Doesn't the `timedelta64` display properly?  You can convert a `timedelta64` value to seconds by using the `td.total_seconds()` method.

Comment: Your error is explicit . There is no operator for float and timedelta. But you can decide timedelta (eg. difference of date) by timedelta. Then if you need a number, look for total_seconds.

Comment: Use `df['duration'] = (df['dropoff_time'] - df['pickup_time'])/pd.Timedelta("1s")`

Comment: @jlandercy Thanks for the advice!  If my dataset is quite large, do I just copy and paste a small sample of it and put it into my post?

Comment: Yes just subsample. You can find useful information in [ask] and [mcve]. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you filtered the first 5 values only by `[:5]`, so it subtracted only 3 values and pandas added `NaN`s for all another rows:

```
df['duration'] = df[:5]['duration'] / np.timedelta64(1, 's')
                 ^^^^^^^        
                  here
```

So the solution is to remove `[:5]`:

```
df['duration'] = (df['dropoff_time'] - df['pickup_time'])/ pd.Timedelta("1s")
```

Or:

```
df['duration'] = (df['dropoff_time'] - df['pickup_time']).td.total_seconds()
```